# How to echo a single session with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I would like to read a single session.

This is how I set all my sessions:

```
$data = array(
    'connection'    => true,
    'sender_db'     => $this->input->post('sender_db'),
    'sender_host'   => $this->input->post('sender_host'),
    'sender_user'   => $this->input->post('sender_user'),
    'sender_pw'     => $this->input->post('sender_pw'),
    'receiver_db'   => $this->input->post('receiver_db'),
    'receiver_host' => $this->input->post('receiver_host'),
    'receiver_user' => $this->input->post('receiver_user'),
    'receiver_pw'   => $this->input->post('receiver_pw'),
);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $this->session->set_userdata($key, $value);
}
```

And this is how I try to read the session `sender_host`:

```
var_dump($this->session->get_userdata('sender_host'));
```

Well, that gives me an array, where all the other sessions are also stored at:

```
array(9) {
    ["connection"]=> bool(true)
    ["sender_db"]=> string(12) "datamigrator"
    ["sender_host"]=> string(9) "localhost"
    ["sender_user"]=> string(4) "root"
    ["receiver_db"]=> string(8) "anything"
    ["sender_pw"]=> string(0) ""
    ["receiver_host"]=> string(8) "anything"
    ["receiver_user"]=> string(8) "anything"
    ["receiver_pw"]=> string(8) "anything"
}
```

How do I get only one session?

I think the problem is how I set the sessions?!

Comment: Read the manual. Its pretty easy to understand. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: its not `get_userdata` only `userdata` to get session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

build array

```
$data = array(
    'connection' => true,
    'sender_db' => $this->input->post('sender_db'),
    'sender_host' => $this->input->post('sender_host'),
    'sender_user' => $this->input->post('sender_user'),
    'sender_pw' => $this->input->post('sender_pw'),
    'receiver_db' => $this->input->post('receiver_db'),
    'receiver_host' => $this->input->post('receiver_host'),
    'receiver_user' => $this->input->post('receiver_user'),
    'receiver_pw' => $this->input->post('receiver_pw'),
);
```

set session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

And read from the session like that:

```
$this->session->userdata('sender_host');
```